# How to install Fatrat from source on Linux (dealing with dependencies)?

Tags: linux, installation, git, dependencies

I'm trying to install latest Fatrat Download Manager from source on my Linux server and I'm not able to deal with dependencies.

There is a GIT repository with latest version of Fatrat (http://git.dolezel.info/?p=fatrat.git;a=summary)
The last commit here mentions PION, one of the dependencies needed to install Fatrat (https://github.com/cloudmeter/pion).

PION has some dependencies on its own, so I installed the latest CMAKE and BOOST C++ library (http://www.boost.org/)

But still PION installation ended with this error:

```
root@debian:/home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion# cmake .
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH = /home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/Bin/
>>> Building Pion version: 5.0.4
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   filesystem
--   regex
--   unit_test_framework
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Log4cplus (missing:  LOG4CPLUS_LIBRARIES)
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
PLUGIN_PATH = /home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/Bin/; EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH = /home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/Bin/
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "pion" in directory /home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/src
OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "pion" in directory /home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
root@debian:/home/lukas/fatrat-source/pion#
```

But OpenSSL is also surely installed.

When trying to install Fatrat its CMAKE ends with (probably because PION is missing):

```
...
[ 99%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fatrat.dir/qrc_resources.cxx.o
Linking CXX executable fatrat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licui18n
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licudata
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_signals-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [fatrat] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fatrat.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@debian:/home/lukas/Downloads/fatrat-1.2.0_beta2#
```

What should I do next to solve this dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian, see "Build-Depends" of previous fatrat versions:

http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/fatrat.git;a=blob;f=debian/control;h=3380baf4748a9cbc3193e6195cfa9858b511a984;hb=HEAD

You can get the build-depends with one command:

```
apt-get build-dep fatrat
```

Comment: Thank you for the command but it is only for the version which is in Debian repository, isn't it? In Debian repository there is an old version (3 years old) which has different dependencies than latest.

Comment: I doubt the dependencies are that much different. But here's a comparison with archlinux fatrat: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/fatrat // and PKGBUILD: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/fatrat -- The make dependencies are 'boost' 'cmake' 'java-environment'. The equivalents for Debian are `libboost-dev` `cmake` and probably `default-jdk`. I would also add `build-essential` package for manual building from source.

Comment: The applications are the same, but the latest Fatrat needs Pion >= 5.0 and I haven't found that in any repo yet. Pion >= 5.0 installing from source gives error I posted in first post..Do you know what to do about it?

Comment: libpion-dev is in debian testing and sid: packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpion-dev and http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pion.html -- you need `libpion-dev` and `libpion` probably. Also check the patch that archlinux packager has used: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/pion-5.0.diff?h=packages/fatrat

Comment: Ok, I was able to install it on a virtual test machine, but in fact I'm trying to install Fatrat on RaspberryPi. There is a problem with Libc6 (dependency for Libpion). More info here: http://superuser.com/questions/660390/unable-to-update-libc6armhf-2-13-38rpi2 . Can you please help with this? Thank you!