# Unable to update libc6:armhf 2.13-38+rpi2

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, aptitude, dependencies

I'm trying to install PION package and I'm unable to do this on RaspberryPi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo aptitude install libpion-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-dev-bin{a} libc6-dev{a} libpion-dev libssl-dev{a} zlib1g-dev{a}
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libssl1.0.0 zlib1g
3 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 633 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/7,037 kB of archives. After unpacking 12.9 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 73253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:armhf 2.13-38+rpi2 (using .../libc6_2.17-93_armhf.deb) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Unpacking replacement libc6:armhf ...
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-93_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed pre-installation script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-93_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: I think you got helped already at http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=58344&p=438387 :) I don't have a raspberry to try it out, sorry. You can also try asking at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ // Btw, I've read that armhf for raspberry pi will not work: https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi -- Debian recommends armel

Comment: You can also try other images/linux distributions, like arch linux: http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi#qt-platform_tabs-ui-tabs2